# Q&A script in Python like OSQA

Tags: osqa

Does anyone have some urls on a question & answer script in Python that is still alive and maintened. OSQA seems dead.

I heard about a clone of Quora-Python but it is dead too.

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: You can have a look at this question : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones